# I want to catch limit Exception and send an email to user when limit Exception occurred in a apex class?

Tags: apex, email, exception

I have a requirement that when a class meets the governor limits i want to send the mail to the specific user.  I want to catch limit Exception and send an email to user when limit Exception occurred in a apex class?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch Limit exceptions.

The best you can do is use the Limits methods to test when you are approaching the limits and act accordingly (email user and stop further processing).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Limits_static_methods.htm

Comment: Thanks Doug for your answer, I did used the limit methods but I am looking any other alternative way to do it.

Comment: Are you running into Limit exceptions a lot? Is there a particular piece of code where it is happening? Perhaps you could concentrate on eliminating the cause of the Limit exceptions then you won't need to worry about catching them....